# Nginx docker proxy container not redirecting?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm attempting to bake the following Nginx reverse proxy configuration into a docker image:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 203.0.113.2;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client IP

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://203.0.113.1:3000;
        }
    }
```

I'm currently just putting that into a volume and mapping it like this:

```
-v nginx-data:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

That works and it when started the container performs as a reverse proxy, but when I bake it in like this:

### Dockerfile

```
  FROM nginx
  COPY gogs.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/gogs.conf
```

Start the container from the image like this:

```
docker run --name gogs-nginx-container -d gogs-nginx
```

And finally visit it at its assigned IP address `http://172.17.0.3/` I just get the "Welcome to Nginx" page, instead of seeing and it does not redirect to `203.0.113.1:3000`.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you confirm your configuration file is getting stored in the right place? Does the container's log, which should contain log messages from nginx, provide any insight?

Comment: When running `docker logs gogs-nginx-container` it only tells me that I tried to connect along with the response codes, which are 304s.  I'm copying the configuring to the same place I mount it when running the vanilla nginx image, so it should work ...

Comment: Correct, it _should_ work. Yet based on your description it seems nginx is not using your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is "Sensitive" to the IP address that it is running on.  In my configuration I have the `server_name 203.0.113.2;` setting, so the container is started it has to be started on that IP address, otherwise the proxy configuration will not trigger.  So this command did the trick:

```
docker run --name gogs-nginx-proxy --net mk1net --ip 203.0.113.2 -d gogs-nginx
```